# SOAP Namespace with http URI

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, saaj

During an upgrade of a 3rd party SOAP API, the vendor has changed their responses to return

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>...
```

instead of previously

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>...
```

Note the change from http to https.

*Is this valid in any way?*

Background: Our Java client code tries to check for a SOAPFault via a call through com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody().hasFault() (saaj-impl-1.3.jar) which fails because the JavaEE standard specifies URI_NS_SOAP_ENVELOPE as the http URI. When the API's https response is returned, the URIs don't match and

```
Jan 16, 2017 3:47:05 PM com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl lookForEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0513: Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized
```

is returned.

*As a workaround, could the SAAJ library behaviour be overridden to force use the http SOAP URI?*

Thank you.

Comment: For additional information, if anyone else ever runs into a similar situation - I found out this morning that the server hosting the API sits behind a load-balancer. It was this that was rewriting all responses and replacing all instances of "http" with "https", not the vendor's upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SOAP 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383492):

> The SOAP envelope has the namespace identifier "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

Therefore the message is not a valid SOAP message. Since SAAJ is designed to follow the SOAP specifications, it won't be able to process that message.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.